# SCP converts German characters from Mac to Ubuntu

Tags: python, utf-8, scp

I am using a Mac texteditor and I have some a `csv` file that contains some German characters:

```
schönheit & gesundheit,1,Yes,03/04/17,-1,1141,in stock,-1,enabled,
```

I am using `scp` to copy the file from my computer to the server:

```
scp -C -i key.pem -r file.csv ubuntu@54.0.0.0:file.csv
```

However what I get is this

```
sch~Znheit & gesundheit,1,Yes,03/04/17,-1,1141,in stock,-1,enabled,
```

and I cannot parse the file with these character.

Do you have any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you check the md5sum for source file and destination file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SCP converts German characters from Mac to Ubuntu

No, `scp` is a binary protocol and it transfers bit to bit. Problem is your editor and its encoding configuration. Open the file in MAC, check what character encoding is used there and when opening the file in Ubuntu, use the same encoding.

Or convert the file initially to UTF-8 to avoid such problems.